# advantages of drush bam vs. drush sql-dump / drush sql-connect

Tags: drush, backups

Is there any comparative advantage in terms of best practice, ease of use, or speed in terms of using the drush back up and migrate command (`drush bam`) or is it just preference?

I'm often using just a simple `drush sql-dump > exportdb.sql` and a `$(drush sql-connect) < importdb.sql` to backup a database. I find it pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There aren't giant differences between the two approaches. Here are a few small differences:

drush sql-dump uses mysqldump program in the background and so is must faster than the pure PHP approach taken by BAM.

You can easily skip tables with sql-dump as well. See the help for this command.

Finally, some folks might want to use sql-sync which does all of these steps in one command. It works faster than sql-dump+sql_connect when one of the machines is remote. It also includes optional data sanitization.

Comment: Moshe, does sql-dump take care of locking tables, maintenance mode, etc to ensure a safe backup?

Comment: We do pass the right params to mysqldump so that it's dump is consistent and safe ... Drupal's maint mode is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the info, and for your work with drush and devel.  I don't know how I could could get anything done w/o those two things.

Answer (score 3):

I think the biggest advantages of bam-backup is that you can choose a profile.  With this you can do a bunch of different things.  The most useful is the ability to exclude the rows from the cache and watchdog tables.  I also think (though I have never confirmed it), that taking a backup this way will use maintenance mode just like via the UI, if you have it configured.  This can result in better backups if you have active traffic.

When I am doing normal backups as safeties, I just use bam-backup.  When I am doing a neuritic backup, or sending a db to a client for deployment, I also take a full backup with MySQL Administrator, which will properly lock tables.