# Should I put my site on maintenance mode before using "drush sql-dump"?

Tags: 7, drush, maintenance-mode

When performing `drush sql-dump`, should I set the site in maintenance mode or will this command makes sure a coherent dump will be generated even if users are busy using Drupal? I can't find confirmation in the [documentation](http://drush.ws/#sql-dump).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Moshe's answer in [advantages of drush bam vs. drush sql-dump / drush sql-connect](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15322/advantages-of-drush-bam-vs-drush-sql-dump-drush-sql-connect), the answer is no.  `drush sql-dump` does the right thing and will result in a consistent backup.

Comment: This is correct. sql-dump calls through to mysqldump or pg_dump, which are guaranteed to be atomic operations.

Comment: many thx for the answer.  Well i am convinced! You point me into the right direction.